# Cannot mount volumes 3 levels deep (on most distros)

Tags: docker, containers, docker-volume

<strike>Picture</strike> output speaks a 1,000 words:

```
$ docker run --rm -v "/a11/a22" -v "/b11/b22/b33" alpine df -h|grep 22
/dev/sda1                58.4G      7.0G     48.4G  13% /a11/a22
/dev/sda1                58.4G      7.0G     48.4G  13% /b11/b22/b33
$ docker run --rm -v "/a11/a22" -v "/b11/b22/b33" busybox df -h|grep 22
/dev/sda1                58.4G      7.0G     48.4G  13% /a11/a22
/dev/sda1                58.4G      7.0G     48.4G  13% /b11/b22/b33
$ docker run --rm -v "/a11/a22" -v "/b11/b22/b33" centos df -h|grep 22
/dev/sda1        59G  7.0G   49G  13% /a11/a22
$ docker run --rm -v "/a11/a22" -v "/b11/b22/b33" ubuntu df -h|grep 22
/dev/sda1        59G  7.0G   49G  13% /a11/a22
$ docker run --rm -v "/a11/a22" -v "/b11/b22/b33" debian df -h|grep 22
/dev/sda1        59G  7.0G   49G  13% /a11/a22
```

On most distros (Centos, Ubuntu, Debian), I cannot create a volume more than 3-levels deep (`/b11/b22/b33`), but 2-levels deep (`/a11/a22`) works everywhere.

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.5, build 633a0ea838
```

Tried it on 2 Win10 WSL1 machines and on a full Centos8 machine.

Comment: Do you have some application code that demonstrates an actual issue?  For better or worse I feel like mounting an anonymous volume on _e.g._ `/usr/src/app/node_modules` is extremely routine and has the desired (and undesired) effects; this shouldn't be an intrinsic Docker limitation.

Comment: @DavidMaze I am not sure how much more of an example do you need. The 3-level deep folder is not there on container (as seen from output of `df -h` command). BTW, I get consistent (non-working) behaviour with both, anon volumes and named volumes

Comment: What part of your application code executes `df -h`?  Is there a difference between Busybox and GNU `df` output that somehow your `grep` isn't capturing?